# What does "composing" mean when symmetry reducing a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading a set of lecture notes describing the process of symmetry reduction of differential equations via Lie algebra methods ([link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268855129_Group_Theory_and_exact_Solutions_of_Partially_Integrable_Differential_Systems?enrichId=rgreq-fc117de3ad2abfb1eb31d57df921d48d-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzI2ODg1NTEyOTtBUzoyNjE5ODg0MzM1MjY3ODRAMTQzOTQ3NDMxODYyOA%3D%3D&el=1_x_2&_esc=publicationCoverPdf)), and I'm stuck at what seems to be a fairly simple point.

The specific example is the Korteweg-DeVries equation,

$$u_t+uu_x+u_{xxx}=0.$$

The Lie algebra will be realized as a vector field

$$\hat{v}=\xi(x,t,u) \partial_x+\tau(x,t,u) \partial_t+\phi(x,t,u)\partial_u.$$

Now I'll directly cut from the notes:

[image]

(I am excerpting but I don't think I'm missing anything critical - check out pg 5 of that link if you want more background).

Anyway, we go through the process of determining the vector field, and end up with

$$\xi=1+t+x,\qquad \tau=1+3t,\qquad \phi=-2u+1$$

So now, I should be integrating these equations, subject to the initial conditions $\tilde{x}(0)=x$, etc. That shouldn't be a problem:

$$\frac{d\tilde{x}}{d\lambda}=1+\tilde{t}+\tilde{x}\rightarrow \tilde{x}=e^\lambda(1+\tilde{t}+x)-(1+\tilde{t})$$
$$\frac{d\tilde{t}}{d\lambda}=1+3\tilde {t}\rightarrow \tilde{t}=\frac{1}{3}e^{3\lambda}(1+3t)-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{d\tilde{u}}{d\lambda}=-2\tilde{u}+1\rightarrow \tilde{u}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-2\lambda}(2u+1)-\frac{1}{2}$$
(we could eliminate $\tilde{t}$ from the first equation, but that won't help what I'm going to say next)

The problem is that in the notes (pg 9), the result is given as

[image]

So for this to match my results I would need to take, for instance,

$$t_0=\frac{1}{3}(1-e^{-3\lambda}),$$

certainly not a constant.

So what am I doing wrong? I guess I am concerned with not understanding what "composing the one-dimensional subgroups" means, but I thought that is describing the process of getting from one solution to another. Like once you get $u(x,t)$, you can use the results above to get another solution $\tilde{u}(\tilde{x},\tilde{t})$.

Comment: "The constants $t_0$, $x_0$, $\lambda$ and $v$ ..." I don't see how one can differentiate with respect to a constant (as in $d\tilde x/d\lambda$). Also, the vector field here is a differential operator, so "composition" may mean simply applying them in order, like $(\partial_x\circ\partial_t)f(x,t)=\partial_x(\partial_t f(x,t))$.